# Box and whisker plot versus date-time in python using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, boxplot

I have the following data:

```
Total_flux_plot_time = [DT.datetime(2018, 8, 18, 8, 15), DT.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 11, 40),
                        DT.datetime(2018, 8, 20, 7, 50), DT.datetime(2018, 8, 21, 7, 15), 
                        DT.datetime(2018, 8, 22, 6, 30, 30), 
                        DT.datetime(2018, 8, 23, 6, 50), 
                        DT.datetime(2018, 8, 24, 9, 10), DT.datetime(2018, 8, 24, 21,35),
                        DT.datetime(2018, 8, 25, 9, 17), DT.datetime(2018, 8, 25, 16, 55), 
                        DT.datetime(2018, 8, 26, 3, 30), DT.datetime(2018, 8, 27, 12, 30), 
                        DT.datetime(2018, 8, 28, 2, 15)]

Total_flux_min = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1230.0, 0.0, 2140.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Total_flux_Q1 = [4.6668, 1.1667, 3.5000999999999998, 1.1667, 0.0, 0.0, 1.1667, 
                 1484.0, 0.0, 2440.0, 28.000000000000004, 0.0, 2.0]                     
Total_flux = [7.0001999999999995, 2.3334, 4.6668, 2.3334, 0.0, 0.0, 1.1667, 
              1598.0, 2.0, 2680.0, 34.0, 0.0, 4.0]
Total_flux_Q3 = [8.1669, 4.6668, 7.0001999999999995, 3.5000999999999998, 0.0, 
                 1.1667, 2.3334, 1707.9999999999998, 2.0, 2820.0, 44.0, 0.0, 6.0]
Total_flux_max = [21.0006, 12.8337, 21.0006, 12.8337, 8.1669, 17.5005, 9.3336, 
                  1976.0000000000002, 12.0, 3279.9999999999995, 88.0, 6.0, 246.0]

d = {'Date_time': Total_flux_plot_time,
     'Minimum': Total_flux_min,
     'First quartile': Total_flux_Q1,
     'Median': Total_flux,
     'Third quartile': Total_flux_Q3,
     'Maximum:': Total_flux_max}

test = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

What I want to do is plot a box and whisker plot in the y-axis using the minimum, Q1, median, Q3 and maximum values versus the date-time in the x-axis. Given the range of values, I am thinking of using 'symlog' on the y-axis. However, I cannot get a boxplot to work versus date-time (using matplotlib). I have been trying to use rectangle from patch but this is more tricky than I envisaged. Presumably, I need to use date2num here but I cannot fathom exactly how. Any advice here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily draw boxplots from the summary stats by using [the Axes.bxp() function](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bxp.html?highlight=bxp#matplotlib-axes-axes-bxp). You have to transform your dictionaries a bit to get them in the right format, and it takes a `positions=` argument to place the boxplots along the x-axis.

As you've guessed, you have to transform your dates using `date2num`, but after that, it's just a matter of finding the right locator/formatter to pretty up the x-axis tick labels. See [the documentation on the `dates` module](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/dates_api.html) for more details.

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
stats = [{'med':med, 'q1':q1, 'q3':q3, 'whislo':low, 'whishi':high} 
         for med,q1,q3,low,high in zip(Total_flux, Total_flux_Q1, Total_flux_Q3, Total_flux_min, Total_flux_max)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_yscale('symlog')
ax.bxp(stats, positions=matplotlib.dates.date2num(Total_flux_plot_time), showfliers=False)

locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=3, maxticks=7)
formatter = mdates.AutoDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, this is great, thanks. The only strange thing is that "ax.axis.set_major_locator(locator)" is throwing the error "attributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'set_major_locator". Am I doing something stupid?

Comment: You must have overloaded `xaxis` by mistake somewhere, try starting from a fresh kernel, and look for other places where you might have used `xaxis`.